# How to use QSettings?

Tags: qt, qsettings

If you have a lot of small classes (that are often created and destroyed), and they all depend on the settings, how would you do that?

It would be nice not to have to connect each one to some kind of "settings changed" signal, and even if I did, all the settings will be updated, even those objects whose settings didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with that myself, I've found it's better to control the save/load settings from a central place.  Do you really need to save/load the settings on a regular basis or can you have a master object (likely with a list of the sub-objects) control when savings actually need to be done?  Or, worst case, as the objects are created and destroyed have them update an in-memory setting map in the parent collection and save when it thinks it should be saved, rather than child object destruction.

Answer (score 1):

One way of implementing it is given below.

If you wish, the central location for the settings can be a singleton derived from `QAbstractItemModel`, and you can easily connect the `dataChanged(...)` signal to various objects as necessary, to receive notifications about changed settings. Those objects can decide whether an applicable setting was changed. By judicious use of helper and shim classes, you can make it very easy to connect your "small classes" with notifications. This would address two issues inherent in the model driven approach to settings.

1. The possibly large number of subscribers, all receiving notifications about the settings they usually don't care about (the *filtering* issue).
2. The extra code needed to connect the subscriber with the item model, and the duplication of information as to what indices of the model are relevant (the *selection* issue).

Both filtering and selection can be dealt with by a shim class that receives all of the `dataChanged` notifications, and for each useful index maintains a list of subscribers. Only the slots of the "interested" objects would then be invoked. This class would maintain the list of subscriber-slot pairs on its own, without offering any signals for others to connect to. It'd use `invokeMethod` or a similar mechanism to invoke the slots.

The selection issue can be dealt with by observing that the subscriber classes will, upon initialization, query the model for initial values of all of the settings that affect their operation - that they are "interested" in. All you need is a temporary proxy model that you create for the duration of the initialization of the subscriber. The proxy model takes the `QObject*` instance of the caller, and records all of the model indices that were queried (passing them onto the singleton settings model). When the proxy model is finally destroyed at the return from the initialization of the subscriber class, it feeds the information about the model indices for this `QObject` to the singleton. A single additional call is needed to let the singleton know about the slot to call, but that's just like calling `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do is to create a class handling all my settings, with one instance per thread. To make it quicker to write this class, I implemented a couple of macros that let me define it like this:

```
L_DECLARE_SETTINGS(LSettingsTest, new QSettings("settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat))
L_DEFINE_VALUE(QString, string1, QString("string1"))
L_DEFINE_VALUE(QSize, size, QSize(100, 100))
L_DEFINE_VALUE(double, temperature, -1)
L_DEFINE_VALUE(QByteArray, image, QByteArray())
L_END_CLASS
```

This class can be instantiated once per thread and then used without writing anything to the file. A particular instance of this class, returned from LSettingsTest::notifier(), emits signals when each property changes. If exposed to QML, each property work as regular Qt property and can be assigned, read and used in bindings.

I wrote more info [here](https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2023/01/lqtutils-settings.html). This is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils) where I placed the macros.